# MySQL 8 get the currently used (default) database name

Tags: mysql

You may use [USE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html)

```
USE <db_name>
```

to use the named database as the default

but how to get the name of the database that is currently used?

So if USE sets the db name, is there a kind of GET or SELECT statement to read database that was set as the default?

Suppose you get a result of a query after many hours and you forgot what particular database that query was targeting. It would be helpful to be able to ask for the default database name to know which database that query result refers to.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch yes, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
select database()
```